# Adding iPod Support to (previously) iPhone Only App

Tags: iphone, app-store, ipod-touch

When I started on my current project, there was already an App in the App Store. This App was iPhone only.

My first task was to test and build a version that also ran on an iPod Touch.

About 3 weeks ago Apple removed the option on iTunes connect to set
the device requirements. And sent an email out to all developers:

> "The App Store requires that you
>   provide metadata about your
>   application before submitting it.
>   While most of this metadata is
>   specified using the iPhone Developer
>   Program Portal, the process for
>   selecting device-related dependencies
>   in iTunes Connect is no longer
>   available. Instead, if your app relies
>   on features that are specific to a
>   device, such as the compass on iPhone
>   3GS, add the
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to
>   your app's Info.plist file to indicate
>   the specific hardware feature
>   required."

When I compiled the iPod compatible version I set the device requirements (`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`) in the **info.plist** to:

1. location-services (gps or skyhook)
2. wi-fi (any device)

However, as the App was originally uploaded and the option for "iPhone
only" set in iTunes connect this appears to be the default.

The kicker is, because Apple have removed this feature there is no way
to change it!

Has anyone come up against this problem? And how did you solve it? Is it possible I have incorrect values in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`?

**UPDATE:** The app will run fine on a iPod Touch if installed as a development version via Xcode. The problem is on the App Store it is listed as iPhone only and when iPod Touch users search in the App store no results are returned.

Comment: I don't have a developer cert so I can't do this, but: make a new HelloWorld app and deploy it to an iPod Touch. Then compare the info.plist. You won't get a definitive answer, but you can rule out some things this way. (If you don't have access to an iPod Touch, send me an email, I'm willing to test a HelloWorld for you.)

Comment: Actually running the app on an iPod is not the issue - I've updated the post to clarify

Comment: With your updated information, this sounds like an issue with iTunes Connect, not a programming-related one.

Comment: I had the same issue as this is what Apple told me to do.  I just had location-services in there.  I am emailing them and will post an answer if i get one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Final solution discovered from multiple sources and email exchanges with Apple.*

**Firstly**, this is only a problem if your App was originally submitted to the App Store and you ticked the iPhone only option.

Steps to avoid compatibility issues:

1. Compile your new App with the required `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in the `info.plist` file. See [Device Support documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html)
2. When submitting your App send an email to **iTunesConnect@apple.com** listing the:

   - Application Name
   - Apple ID
   - Bundle Identifier
   - Bundle Version
   - Required Capabilities

Explain that your when approved the reviewer needs to TURN OFF the default device requirements originally set in iTunes Connect.

If you don't send an email *before* your App is approved you will have to submit another binary even if the iTunes Connect override is set correctly.

Plan your upgrade carefully, it has taken well over 2 weeks to track down and resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking on the apple developer forums it sounds like the best way is to email devprogram@apple.com to sort it out.  In only post that got resolved that is what the user did, and what I am going to do right now.

Comment: I agree that is probably the best plan of action.

Comment: Confirmed.  Apple emailed me back and said they did something on their end to remove the restriction and asked me to push an update and it will accept the UIReq... settings