# How do I target an app to work on ipad 2 or newer (not ipad 1) before submission to appstore?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

My app is for the iPad 2 only. I have seen other answers involving setting the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key, but I need to exclude the iPad 1 because of the CPU power, not any specific hardware feature.

I would like the app to show up in the appstore for people in the future also (iPad 3 etc. should have equal or stronger processor than 2), so I need only exclude iPad 1 specifically.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) to require `front-facing-camera`. I don't think they are going to cut down on features. There isn't any other way, it seems.

Comment: I think this will be your best bet @materialvision.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to go with this option... but what happens if I at a later time decide to make an ipad 1 version. I guess it should be ok to remove this restriction then?

Comment: Not sure, I know you are not allowed to increase restrictions on UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (this would disable purchases on update) but *I think* you are allowed to remove them. Worst case scenario, you will have to ask Apple to remove the restriction. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431825/adding-ipod-support-to-previously-iphone-only-app (tho this guy ticked a device x only option, I dont remember if there is a iPad 2 only option)

Comment: Does Apple approve apps that use this method? I read somewhere on here that they reject apps for setting UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities for hardware that's not being used.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be no Processor_MHz_GHz, CPU_core_count or GPU_shader_count keys currently documented for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities plist.  And Apple currently appears not to allow adding more hardware restriction keys to existing apps already in the App store.

So you appear to be out-of-luck, if you don't want to risk requiring a camera.   Or just selling a new app (not an update) to support hypothetical future products.

ADDED/UPDATE (2012-September): You can now exclude a 1st generation iPad by specifying iOS 6.x as the minimum Deployment target in your build settings, since an iOS 6 update is not offered by Apple for the 1st gen iPad, whereas an iPad 2 and newer will run iOS 6.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, CPU power is a hardware feature. Try disabling the ARM version of the iPad 1, so only newer iDevices will be supported.
Keep in mind though when disabling certain ARM versions you might also be excluding the older iPods and iPhones if your app is an universal one.

Bryan

Comment: Won't work.  Both the iPad and the iPad are armv7 architecture.