# Set the app compatible for only iPad2 and iPad3 while uploading the App to AppStore?

Tags: ios

How to make the app compatible for only iPad2 and iPad3 while submitting in App Store ? I mean that the user with iPad1 cant download the app using iPad1. Is there any option to set to our app while uploading to AppStore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Check the below link.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235979/how-do-i-target-an-app-to-work-on-ipad-2-or-newer-not-ipad-1-before-submission)

By setting UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in plist, we can set our App Compatible for corresponding ipad or iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, you've no other solution to solve it, unless you put the limitation as description about the application in **AppStore** while you are uploading it.

Comment: I got the answer. Check the below link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235979/how-do-i-target-an-app-to-work-on-ipad-2-or-newer-not-ipad-1-before-submission

By setting UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, we can set our App Compatible for corresponding ipad or iPhone.


Thank You.